# Creating a BehaviourSubject with an Int

Tags: kotlin

How can I create an instance of this Subject with an Int:

```
class NonNullableBehaviourSubject<T : Any>(defaultValue: T) : Subject<T>() {
   private val behaviourSubject = BehaviorSubject.createDefault<T>(defaultValue)
}
```

I then create an instance of NonNullableBehaviourSubject like this:

```
val emailValidationSubject = NonNullableBehaviourSubject(Int)
```

But I then get a compile error using this:

```
emailValidationSubject.onNext(error?.errorResId)
```

The compile error I get is:

```
Required: Companion.Int
Found: Int?
```

Also, Int must not be nullable. Yet, NonNullableBehaviourSubject does define a nullable parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `error` object has nullable type, and you use safe call (`?.`) on it, so the whole expression is nullable.
To make the value non-nullable you can either assert value is not null (`error!!.errorResId` will crash if `error` is `null`, `error?.errorResId!!` will crash if the whole expression is null) or provide the fallback value for null case (`(error ?: DEFAULT_ERROR).errorResId` or `error?.errorResId ?: DEFAULT_ERROR_RES`).

Comment: It also should be `NonNullableBehaviourSubject(0)` (or some other `Int`) rather than `NonNullableBehaviourSubject(Int)`.