# Preventing code in subscribe from executing when subject is initialized

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2

In this code:

```
class RequestNewPasswordFragment {

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        btnRequestNewPassword.setOnClickListener {
            view.hideKeyboard()
            viewModel.validateEmail(txtInputLayoutEmail.textValue)
        }

        disposables += viewModel.emailValidationSubject
            .observeOnMainThread()
            .subscribe { validationResponse ->
               viewModel.requestNewPassword()
            }

}
```

When the fragment is initialized, the emailValidationSubject gets initialized. This causes the code in subscribe to execute, which makes a call to the requestNewPassword in the viewModel. I want to avoid this. I want this to only be called when btnRequestNewPassword is clicked. The code in subscribe should only get called when the viewModel needs to validate the input. How can I prevent `viewModel.requestNewPassword()` from being called when the fragment is initialized?

Comment: if the code in subscribe runs immediately it means that the viewModel.emailValidationSubject return an item in subscribe i think that you should provide viewModel object to find the problem because i think that problem is in viewModel not here

Comment: Likely reason is that `emailValidationSubject` is being initialized in `viewModel`'s `init {..}` or like this `emailValidationSubject.also { .. }` in the viewmodel. Avoid that. `emailValidationSubject` should fire events using `.onNext(..)` in the function `validateEmail(..)`

Comment: please edit your question with the code for `emailValidationSubject`, if it's declared as BehaviorSubject, it will always emit a value when subscribed to, hence you are seeing the `viewModel.requestNewPassword()` being called once it subscribes to emailValidationSubject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming your `emailValidationSubject` is a BehaviourSubject based on your previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57996878/creating-a-behavioursubject-with-an-int).

[BehaviourSubject](http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html) will always emit an value on subscription, hence you need to provide an initial value.

> it begins by emitting the item most recently emitted by the source Observable (or a seed/default value if none has yet been emitted)

You need to use a [PublishSubject](http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html):

> PublishSubject emits to an observer only those items that are emitted by the source Observable(s) subsequent to the time of the subscription.